# ValueError: The lengths of the data (1) and the error bars (3) don't match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to add error bars to my chart, and even though I have 3 data points on the Y index and am adding 3 yerr points. I get the following error:

ValueError: The lengths of the data (1) and the error 3 do not match

Here is my code:

```
mydict = {'A':24, 'B':22,'C':1}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict, index=['Yes'])

df.plot(kind='bar', y=['A','B','C'], yerr=[.14,.15,.03]).legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yerr` should match the shape of the input.

This would work well on the transposed dataframe:

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar',
        yerr=[.14,.15,.03]
       ).legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

[image: transposed bars]

Here you need to use individual lists:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', y=['A','B','C'],
        yerr=[[.14],[.15],[.03]]
       ).legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

Or using `numpy`:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', y=['A','B','C'],
        yerr=np.array([.14,.15,.03])[:,None]
       ).legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

[image: bars]

*NB. I used larger (fake) `yerr` values to generate the images for better visualization*